Newtonian fields interaction
Newtonian gravity is a linear approximation of a very weak field, such as gravitational waves. But why do gravitational waves interact with each other while Newtonian fields don't?

My cats are feline, like lions. But why do lions roar while my cats don't?

Because they are two fundamentally different things.
The Newtonian approximation is the low-mass or equivalently high-distance approximation of the Schwarzschild solution to the Einstein field equations, while a gravitational wave is an approximation of the extremely-complex effect that high-energy events (supernovae, neutron star collisions, black hole mergers) have on spacetime. They’re not related and don’t share many properties.
Fundamentally, gravitational waves are approximated as linear, but they still describe a spacetime that has been altered by an external source. The Newtonian approximation usually considers spacetime to be entirely flat, rather than slightly curved as GW approx.s usually do. In reality, Newtonian fields do interact, but the point of the Newtonian approx. is that that interaction is functionally negligible, whereas for the GW approx.s it’s not.

Starting from the geodesic equation, applying the limits that we experience as speeds much lower than that of light ( v << c ), with gravitational fields stable over time ( ∂g / ∂t = 0) and weak, therefore considered as a small perturbation of the flat Minkowski spacetime ( gμv = ημv + hμv ), it allows us to make many simplifications in the calculations. So what we simplify to get to Newtonian physics appears to be not the perturbation but the local space simplified as if it were flat.

Considering in the calculations the time coordinate separately we obtain: d^2 x^0
/ds^2 = 0; while from the spatial ones a
gradient is obtained: d^2 x/ds^2 + 1/2 ( ∇ h00) (dct / ds)^2 = 0 thus arriving through new calculations and substitutions at the equation:
d^2 x/dt^2 = -∇ c^2 h00 1/2 which is very similar to the Newtonian one we know:
d^2 x/dt^2 = -∇ϕ where therefore ϕ = -1/2 c^2 h00 in turn equal to -GM/R so as we know
h00 = -2GM/ c^2R.

It will therefore be this perturbation that creates the ϕ existing in a flat spacetime around a non-relativistic mass: g00 = 1 -2GM/ c^2R .
We can test it for example with a mass of 0.26 kg that develops a  ϕ  at 3 cm from its center of -5.78 x 10^-10 m^2 s^-2:
h00 = -2GM/ c^2R = - 3.46 x10^-11 m^3 s^-2
/ 2.7 x10^15 m^3 s^-2 = - 1.28x10^-26
and being - GM/R = h00 1/2 c^2 = - 1.28x10^-26 x 4.5 x10^16 m^2 s^-2 = -5.76 x 10^-10 m^2 s^-2 which is what we expected.

Nothing new up to this point, but why can η00 undergo a perturbation by just one h00 and not two or more at a time? What is << 1 is the same perturbation -2GM/ c^2 R that gives rise to the Newtonian ϕ so how can the interactions between them be negligible?

You didn’t use MathJax in any of that so it’s very hard to interpret; the best I can say is that the fundamental thing being missed is that Newtonian approximations deal with spacetime that is entirely flat in the approximation (Newtonian gravity doesn’t mention time dilation or length contraction) and a GW specifically deals with a perturbation that represents curved spacetime. So GWs interact, Newtonian approx.s don’t. If you’d like I’d recommend reading MTW’s Gravitation which deals with both approximations extensively and in great depth. @DamyToma

Yes, I'm sorry, it's actually not very comprehensible written like that, but what I wanted to make clear is that interactions could be hypothesized between the perturbations that create the potential (which is in any case associated with phenomena such as time dilation) not between flat spacetime. Anyway, I'll take your advice, thanks.
